# React Native and React Native Web- document is not defined error

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-web

I am trying to create a currency converter app. I am trying to create 2 dropdowns for selecting currencies. During that, I figured out that the library I am using, "react native material dropdown", does not work on web. This is the Error that I am getting with react native material dropdown on web:
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw5Cd.png)

So, I added react native web to my app and used the docs to add the following 2 lines of code to the react native app:

```js
AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
AppRegistry.runApplication('App', {rootTag: document.getElementById('react-root')});
```

This is my entire "App.js":

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';
import { Header } from 'react-native-elements';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import {Dropdown} from 'react-native-material-dropdown';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <View style={styles.appContainer}>
          <Header
            backgroundColor={'#2CC779'}
            centerComponent={{
              text: 'Currency Converter',
              style: {
                color: '#fff',
                fontSize: 20,
              },
            }}
          />
          <Text style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>Enter currency to convert from:</Text>


          <Text style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>Enter currency to convert to:</Text>
          

          
        </View>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  appContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#18C6C9',
  },
  currencyInput: {
    marginTop: 50,
    width: '80%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    height: 40,
    textAlign: 'center',
    borderWidth: 4,
    outline: 'none',
  },
  convertButton: {
    width: '50%',
    height: 55,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    padding: 10,
    margin: 100,
  },
  convertButtonText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
AppRegistry.runApplication('App', {rootTag: document.getElementById('react-root')});
```

This is my "package.json":

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "expo-constants": "~12.1.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "4.9.2",
    "react-native-elements": "*",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "*"
  }
}
```

But now, after that, expo is saying that "document is not defined": [screenshot of second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMoXR.png)

What do I do next and how should I proceed?
(P.S. Keep in mind that this is inside an online Expo environment in the Snack editor)

Comment: is it working or still the same problem? @whitehatcoder

Comment: I got the answer. So how do I fetch id of an element in react native without using document?

Comment: Or is there another way to run react native on web?

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: react-native is specially used only for mobile apps for web purpose you can use reactjs or other framework @whitehatcoder

Answer (score 0):

The below line is only applicable for webapp, not applicable for react native app. That's the reason why `document` is undefined.

```
AppRegistry.runApplication('App', {rootTag: document.getElementById('react-root')});
```